# Discord.py Message when member joins specific channel

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Good afternoon.

Again I have a question about a discord python bot.
So I want to do something like a support script. My idea is to write all supporter a command if they are on duty which is saved in a json file. That's no problem but my problem is that I want the user to recieve how many supporter are on duty while connecting to a specific voice channel named: 'Support-Room'. Has anyone an idea how I can write a script that when a member joins this specific voice channel he gets a message with for example: member.send('You are now in the Support-Room. Please wait till a Supporter moves you.')

```
@bot.command()
async def on_member_join(member):
    for channel in bot.get_all_channels():
        if channel.name == 'Support-Room':
            await member.send(''You are now in the Support-Room. Please wait till a Supporter moves you.')
```

That is what I tried but it does not work :(

Comment: `@bot.command()` typo --> `bot.command`

Comment: Do you really (want to) use an `event` in a `command`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mixing events and a bot command is not how it will work. Using an `event` is the solution.
We have to use an event called `on_voice_state_update`, see the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_voice_state_update#discord.on_voice_state_update) for more information.

***Have a look at the following code:***

```py
@bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    channel = before.channel or after.channel

    if channel.id == VoiceChannelID: # Insert voice channel ID
        if before.channel is None and after.channel is not None: # Member joins the defined channel
            await member.send("Your text here.") # Send a DM to the member who joined
```

**What did we do?**

- Checked the channel he was in before and is now in.
- Checked if the joined channel matches the defined channel.
- Sent a message to the user if the channel is correct.